# Вывести объекты на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

хочу вывести обьекты на странныцу с моих условиям.

```js
var products = [
  {
   name: "chair",
   inventory: 5,
   unit_price: 45.99
  },
  {
   name: "table",
   inventory: 10,
   unit_price: 123.75
  },
  {
   name: "sofa",
   inventory: 2,
   unit_price: 399.50
  }
  ];
  var input=$("input");
  var button=$("button");
  button.click(function() {
   for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++) {
   if(products[i].inventory <= input.val()) {
    // console.log(products[i]);
   document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = products[i];
   }
  }
  });
```

```html
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<input type="text" >
<button>Fix</button>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы. Этот знак - для Вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var products = [{
    name: "chair",
    inventory: 5,
    unit_price: 45.99
  },
  {
    name: "table",
    inventory: 10,
    unit_price: 123.75
  },
  {
    name: "sofa",
    inventory: 2,
    unit_price: 399.50
  }
];
var input = $("input");
var button = $("button");
button.click(function() {
  var content = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i].inventory <= +input.val()) {
      content.push(JSON.stringify(products[i]));
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = content.join("<br />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<input type="text">
<button>Fix</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```